# Cloudinary URLs break with Mongoid 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, mongoid, carrierwave, cloudinary

I've using the Cloudinary gem, which up until now has worked fine as an embedded `Photo` model in Mongoid:

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave
  def public_id
    return model.id
  end
end

class Photo
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps  
  embedded_in :place#, :inverse_of => :photos, :autosave => true
  mount_uploader :image, PhotoUploader
  #...
end
```

However, after upgrading to Mongoid 3, getting the image URL no longer works. Consider this Photo model:

```
1.9.3p194 :019 > p
 => #<Photo _id: 507bc3c82a450b14bd00e00a, _type: nil, created_at: 2012-10-15 08:05:28 UTC, updated_at: 2012-10-15 08:05:28 UTC, image_filename: nil, caption: nil, original_url: "http://www.reactionny.com//images/assets/101755_316529.JPG", image: "v1350288333/507bc3c82a450b14bd00e00a.jpg"> 
1.9.3p194 :020 > p.image
 => /assets/fallback/default.png 
1.9.3p194 :021 > p.image_url
 => "/assets/fallback/default.png" 
1.9.3p194 :022 > p['image']
 => "v1350288333/507bc3c82a450b14bd00e00a.jpg"
```

Why is it no longer returning the fully-qualified Cloudinary URL, in the form `http://res.cloudinary.com/XXXXXX/image/upload/v1350288842/507bc5ca2a450b14bd00e896.jpg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `carrierwave-mongoid` changed the name of the field in which the image is saved from `yyy` to `yyy_filename`.
In your model inspection printing you can see that `image_filename` is `nil`.

The integration with the Cloudinary GEM and CarrierWave seems to be working fine, but you need to migrate your model.
The relevant field used to be called 'image' and it's now called 'image_filename'. You should probably update your model to use the new field name and copy all values.

Another possible solution would be to specifically set the attribute name using `mount_on`:

```
mount_uploader :image, PhotoUploader, mount_on: :image
```